# Long loading time when opening OLE DB Source in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2017

I have an SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) package in Visual Studio that contains a Data Flow Task. The Data Flow Task reads data from an OLE DB Source and loads it into an OLE DB Destination. The OLE DB Source is connected to a view in my database, and the SELECT statement for that view takes around 3 minutes and 20 seconds to execute.

The issue I'm facing is that when I try to open the OLE DB Source component in Visual Studio, it takes an extremely long time, sometimes over an hour, to load. This makes it very frustrating to edit the source and work on my SSIS package.

I have tried a few things to resolve this issue, but none of them have provided a satisfactory solution.

At this point, I'm not sure what else I can do to address this issue. I'm open to any suggestions or advice on how to improve the loading time when opening the OLE DB Source component in Visual Studio.

Is there anything else I can try to speed up the loading time? Are there any additional settings or optimizations that I might have missed? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have had similar issues (not as extreme as an hour).  My situation is I am on a Remove Box login through VDI.  (Remote Desktop).  I have Visual Studio installed but my files are saved on One Drive (network storage).  When I try to open packages or inspect some connections it takes a very long time to load.  I found it is because it is on a Network box reaching out to a network drive to get the file then has to verify the connection string.  When I moved the project files to the C drive of the networked PC, it sped up tremendously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue as the OP and found the underlying cause in my case.

**Summary**

Before finding this post and diving deeper in the investigation, I simply updated my query with TOP 1 while developing the ETL.  Although, @Tom Thomson's workaround of using a SQL Command for the Data access mode and prefixing it with `SET ROWCOUNT 0` works and is less of an assle, investigation and testing showed that the SET ROWCOUNT is simply not needed.  The simple fact of using SQL Command is enough for SSIS to issue a SP_PREPARE command instead of the SELECT * query and retrieve the metadata quickly.

So the shortest answer if you're having an issue with a long loading time when opening an OLE DB data source is: Use 'SQL Command' instead of 'Table or view'.

For more details, continue reading.

**Investigation details**

But to understand the issue I did look at the activities behind the validation.  It's executing:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1 
SELECT * FROM myView
```

It's not performing the `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` query as stated by another user.

The SSIS default method works quite well with most of the tables and views I've tested.  However, I'm having issues with my recent views.

Without ROWCOUNT my view takes 1 second, with it, it takes forever (I cancelled before completing).  The SET ROWCOUNT 1 is affecting the execution plan.

- Without ROWCOUNT no steps went over 100% of planned rows to retrieve
  and matches the number of rows in the underlying tables or less.
- With it, there seems to be more steps and the expected rows to
  retrieve is very low but ends up retrieving all the table rows or a
  lot more then the number of rows that exist in the table/index
  specified in a step.

But the biggest difference is that, with ROWCOUNT, a Table Spool is inserted in the plan and just keep chugging in rows:

[image: Execution plan showing Table Spool step]

Without ROWCOUNT, there's no Table Spool in the plan and no excessive row processing:
[image: Execution plan showing absence of Table Spool step]

With that information I removed the Linked Server part of my query and tested again and this time both executions returned quickly, with and without ROWCOUNT.

I have other complex queries as source and didn't have issues with them in the past,  and did remember seeing SSIS performing `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` commands so I took a look into them and noticed that it's because I'd wrapped them in Stored Procedure (SP) and use SQL command as the Data access mode in my OLE DB Source.  The validation step issues a `sp_prepare` statement on the SP followed by a `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` command.  I embedded my problematic query in a SP and it worked just fine.  It loaded very quickly.

After further testing, I found out that the underlying reason it works well with a SP is simply because SSIS issues a SP_PREPARE statement when using **ANY** SQL Command as the Data access mode.  Therefore, the other answer that adds SET ROWCOUNT 0 is not totally accurate, as that prefix is simply not needed.

With that, I'm wondering why, if other more effecient methods like `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` or `sp_prepare` exists and works to retrieve the metadata, SSIS uses SET ROWCOUNT 1 to retrieve the information when "Table or view" is selected?

Answer (score 1):

After investigating the issue further, I discovered that the root cause of the long loading time when opening the OLE DB Source in Visual Studio for my SSIS package was related to the use of the SET ROWCOUNT statement.

By default, SSIS in Visual Studio sets the ROWCOUNT to 1 before executing the SQL statement in the OLE DB Source. This can significantly impact the execution time, especially if the underlying query retrieves a large amount of data.

To resolve this issue, I made the following changes:

I modified the OLE DB Source component to use an SQL Command instead of a table/view name directly.
In the SQL Command, I added the statement SET ROWCOUNT 0 before the actual SELECT statement.
Here's an example of how the SQL Command looks like in the OLE DB Source:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 0
SELECT * FROM [view]
```

Setting the ROWCOUNT to 0 effectively removes the limit on the number of rows returned, allowing the query to retrieve the entire result set.

After making this change, the loading time of the OLE DB Source in Visual Studio improved significantly, and I can now edit the source without any delays.

Comment: Try it without SET ROWCOUNT altogether.  It should work just as well.  The simple fact that you're using SQL Command as the source is enough to make the difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you open an SSIS package, it needs to validate the metadata of any data flow components. An hour seems egregious but when you open the package your or a DBA should be looking at that source server and identify the why of the delay. Something is blocking/preventing the validation from occurring. If you don't know how to do this, grab something like http://whoisactive.com and mash that stored procedure or better, dump to a table in a loop http://whoisactive.com/docs/25_capturing/ and then analyze what the heck is happening.

Opening SSIS projects is a synchronous operation - based on the "helpful" information Visual Studio 201_ tells me and helpfully offers to disable the SSIS handlers which is great except I need to author SSIS packages   But that's usually a 15 to 30 second ish delay, not minutes and certainly not hours.

Working offline is likely not an option if you're modifying a Data Flow as any change to an item forces a validation of metadata.

Under the covers, a 2012+ SSIS package will validate SQL Server metadata via the `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` dynamic management object. Barring differences with SET options, you ought to be able to plumb in your query as the [first parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and see how long it takes for the data shape to be returned.

Less probable options:

- virus scanners
- slow disk on your machine
- poor network connection
- low memory
- overly complex packages (everything gets validated when you open the package, not just the 1 data flow you care about so a package with 100 data flows is going to take much longer to validate - ready to edit - than 100 packages with a single data flow)